# Firebase Cloud Functions + React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-functions

can you help me please?
I am trying to build an app(like cloud twitter) using ReactJS with cloud functions on firebase as back-end.
I put my proxy link to cloud functions in package.json, but i get the error: Failed to load resource: //the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)// or //GET http://localhost:3000/screams 404 (Not Found)//.
I restarted the npm start,my database is ok, but still getting this error
Can you tell alternative solutions please?
The code from home page is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';


class home extends Component {
    state = {
        screams: null
    }
     componentDidMount(){
            axios.get('/screams')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
                this.setState({
                    screams: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
     }
    render() {
        let recentScreamsMarkup = this.state.screams ? (
        this.state.screams.map(scream => <p> {scream.body}</p>)
        ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
        );
        return (
            <Grid container spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
                    {recentScreamsMarkup}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <p>Profile...</p>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

export default home
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the full path `axios.get('localhost:3000/screams')`

Comment: Still doesnt work. It says  GET localhost:3000/screams net::ERR_FAILED.Thank you anyway

Comment: Try with the protocol aswell: `axios.get('http://localhost:3000/screams')`

Comment: Might be a CORS issue, you can try with this plugin if you are using Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US

Comment: Thank you for your time. Still trying to figure this

Comment: You were right about CORS. I installed the CORS in my functions and then put:`const cors = require('cors'); app.use(cors());` And it shows the screams from Database !Thank you!